# Password incorrect or New Password invalid. New Password length minimum: 4. Non-alphanumeric characters required: 0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, change-password

Unable to change password. Have set the following in webConfig and in .aspx. The value for current. new and confirm password is correct. BUt everytime this error is thrown "Password incorrect or New Password invalid. New Password length minimum: 4. Non-alphanumeric characters required: 0"
WebConfig

```
 <membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

ChangePassword.aspx

```
    <asp:ChangePassword  CancelDestinationPageUrl="Default.aspx" BackColor="#96bd0d" ID="ChangePassword1" runat="server">
  <ChangePasswordTemplate>
       <table cellpadding="1"  cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellpadding="4">                           
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:Label ID="CurrentPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                                    AssociatedControlID="CurrentPassword">Password</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 166px" align="right">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="CurrentPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CurrentPasswordRequired" runat="server"
                                    ControlToValidate="CurrentPassword" ForeColor="red"
                                   ErrorMessage="Required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:Label ID="NewPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                                    AssociatedControlID="NewPassword">New Password</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:166px" align="right">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="NewPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NewPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="NewPassword" ForeColor="red"
                                   ErrorMessage="Required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:Label ID="ConfirmNewPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                                    AssociatedControlID="ConfirmNewPassword">Confirm New Password</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 166px" align="right">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmNewPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmNewPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="ConfirmNewPassword"   ForeColor="red"                                    
                                   ErrorMessage="Required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" ></asp:Literal>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:Button ID="ChangePasswordPushButton" runat="server" Text="Change Password" 
                                    CommandName="ChangePassword"
                                    ValidationGroup="ChangePassword1" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 166px" align="center">
                                <asp:Button ID="CancelPushButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                    CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>              
        </table>
  </ChangePasswordTemplate>
```